# tomcat 8.5.8.0 can not find some static resources(not all),until I exec 'touch filename' at system

Tags: tomcat, touch, http-status-code-404

I use tomcat 8.5.8.0 on docker(linux),when I visit some  static resources(html / js ),it return 404 error,But  I confirm that the file is exists. after I exec command "touch filename(which happened 404)", it can be visit .

my configs:

context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!-- The contents of this file will be loaded for each web application -->
<Context> 
    <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>
    <WatchedResource>${catalina.base}/conf/web.xml</WatchedResource>
    <Resources allowLinking="true" />

</Context>
```

server.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<Server port="18012" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="on" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener" />


  <GlobalNamingResources>

    <Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
              type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
              description="User database that can be updated and saved"
              factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
              pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />
  </GlobalNamingResources>
  <Service name="Catalina">
    <Connector port="8012" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               maxThreads="1000"
               minProcessors="100"
               maxProcessors="1000"
               minSpareThreads="100"
               maxSpareThreads="1000"
               enableLookups="false"
               URIEncoding="utf-8"
               acceptCount="1000"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               disableUploadTimeout="ture"
               redirectPort="8443" />


    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">

      <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">

        <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
               resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
      </Realm>

      <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">

        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
               prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt"
               pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />


      </Host>
    </Engine>
  </Service>
</Server>
```

ps :before problems arise,there is some request(100+) to download a file sized 30M

Thanks in advance guys ;-)

Comment: Hi, Shawn, it is better to give more detail, for example your config file, sample codes to ask a clearer question.

Comment: tks for your advance .

Comment: The code is very simple，.html and .js file